# Characters in the upcoming Dark Universe movies

Tags: the-mummy-2017, dark-universe

The recently released movie Mummy starring Tom Cruise is a part of upcoming series of Dark Universe which is supposed to have many movies and characters . What are the characters involved in this universe and upcoming movies?

Comment: So they still doing it after two failures?

Comment: Well, I mean DCEU is still running right? Same concept I guess... :P

Comment: What are the *two* failures? I'm aware of the Tom Cruise - Mummy movie, but what was the other one?

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles Dracula untold was supposed to be the start of the Dark Universe...

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea about that movie. Never heard of it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per latest update none for now.

From [variety](https://variety.com/2019/film/news/universal-finds-director-invisible-man-studios-monster-legacy-1203117708/):

> “Throughout cinematic history, Universal’s classic monsters have been reinvented through the prism of each new filmmaker who brought these characters to life,” said Peter Cramer, Universal’s president of production. **“We are excited to take a more individualized approach for their return to screen**, shepherded by creators who have stories they are passionate to tell with them.”

So the first individualized Universal monster movie will be *The Invisible Man* (not *The Bride of Frankenstein* which was expected) -- but Universal have changed their mind so many times so we can never be sure.

Previously *Dracula Untold* was supposed to be the first film in Dark Universe which was a moderate success too but later [Kurtzman confirmed that it's not](http://collider.com/the-mummy-universal-monsters-shared-universe/#dr-jekyll-creature-from-the-black-lagoon). And *The Mummy* (2017) also underperformed as per expectation and now this individualized approach seems to indicate the end of Dark Universe for now.

Comment: are they still looking for Depp as title character in invisible man?

Comment: @Vishwa he is considered for some other Universal monster film as per rumours

Answer (score 7):

Subject to change given the lack of success of *The Mummy*:

- Frankenstein
- Bride of Frankenstein
- Dracula
- Creature from the Black Lagoon
- Phantom of the Opera
- Hunchback of Notre Dame
- The Invisible Man

> “We know we’re going to do Frankenstein, Bride of Frankenstein, Dracula, Creature from the Black Lagoon, Phantom of the Opera, Hunchback of Notre Dame, Invisible Man,”
>
> ....according to Alex Kurtzman (creative mind behind the Dark Universe, and director and producer of The Mummy)
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/mummy-producer-says-phantom-hunchback-added-dark-universe)</sup>

Other possibles...

- The Wolfman
- Van Helsing
- Dr Jekyl & Mr Hyde

Note that according to [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Monsters#Dark_Universe), some (or all) of these are in doubt.

> The second film for the franchise was slated to be a remake of Bride of Frankenstein, rumored to star Angelina Jolie in the title role. The film was given a release date of February 18, 2019, and was set to begin filming in February of 2018. On November 8, 2017, Alex Kurtzman and Chris Morgan moved on to other projects, leaving the future of the Dark Universe in doubt. On January 15, 2018, it was reported by Omega Underground that the film's production team had been re-assembled and the franchise was now eyeing Gal Gadot for the lead role.

Comment: Which characters are included like Frankenstein's monster, Invisible Man,Wolfman etc. Also @Paulie_D can you name the actors playing these characters.

Comment: @codeczar No...no names are confirmed (although Johnny Depp was rumoured for the Invisible Man) becuase, right now... **none** of these are definite.

Comment: Gal Gadot as the Bride of Frankenstien, would be very interesting - I would love to see something like this

Answer (score 3):

When the Dark Universe concept was formulated, the following movies were considered to be part of the Dark Universe:

1. The Mummy (2017)
2. The Bride of the Frankenstein (~2019)
3. The Creature From The Black Lagoon (~2019)
4. The Invisible Man (~2020)
5. Van Helsing (TBA)
6. The Wolfman (TBA)

But with the failure of The Mummy, only Bride of Frankenstein is set in stone...

**[Source](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/the-mummy/feature/a829209/universal-dark-universe-the-mummy-bride-of-frankenstein-the-invisible-man-trailer-release-date/)**

And going by rumour territory, check this **[source](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/universal-monsters/255097/complete-upcoming-dark-universe-monsters-movie-schedule)**:

- Dr. Jekyll & Mr. Hyde
- The Phantom of the Opera
- The Hunchback of Notre Dame